# Django: After a celery task error the date time input format is invalid on the site

Tags: django, celery

I am having a rather strange issue with one of my sites.
I have a Django site (using uWSGI and NGINX) and a celery instance.
Both celery and the site is managed through supervisord.

I have the following setting in my settings.py file:

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = (
    '%d/%m/%Y',
    '%Y-%m-%d',
)
```

However, if one of the celery tasks throws an error (or it seems to be consistent with when that happens), suddenly when I input dates in a form on the site, it says it's an invalid date.

I can't find any information about this anywhere.
Does anyone have any idea why this might happen?

Comment: I don't have the celery error now. They are quite infrequent, but I'll post it as soon as it comes through again.

Comment: This has happened again without me even receiving an error message.
It seems that after the site has been up and running for a few days, the date format seems to become "incorrect"

Answer (score 1):

We're having a similar problem and it's driving me crazy, I've solved it but I can find neither the cause nor a pattern to reproduce the bug.

We have the `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` defined on the settings as well, and the validation is working as expected. Now we're moving a heavy feature that's causing Bad Gateways to a celery task, and certain form will be initialized inside the task. The first day of testing everything was working fine, but yesterday we encountered some problems.

We have two `DateField` in the form, same format, and sometimes one of them throws a validation error. I can't find any pattern with the dates; every time I reload the page, select the dates and launch the task, the behaviour seems to be different even selecting the same dates (sometimes it gets validated, sometimes not). If I use `pdb` and manually initialize the form before calling the task, it's validated correctly. I've also checked that the form data inside the task is exactly the same, so the problem must be somehow related to `Celery` and the `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` setting.

Eventually I solved it by defining the optional `input_formats` argument on the problematic field of the form:

`class DateFilterForm(forms.Form):
    date_from = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.DateInput(
            format='%d/%m/%Y', attrs={'class': 'date_input'}
        )
    )
    date_to = forms.DateField(
        input_formats = ['%d/%m/%Y'],
        widget=forms.DateInput(
            format='%d/%m/%Y', attrs={'class': 'date_input'}
        )
    )`

And that way it always works fine, though I haven't been able to figure out the logic behind it. Our current environment uses `Django==1.4.16` and `celery==2.5.1`, if anyone is interested (we hope to upgrade that soon, so I'll check if that solves the original problem).

Comment: I forgot about this nightmare! I have put that project away (don't even think I have the source for it anymore). I remember changing the locales on the server and trying all sorts of things. If you have `USE_L10N = True` in your settings file then the local will take precedence.